# Connect R with Access tables give error messages in 64-bit windows

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc

I tried to connect R with Access tables using the following code. It worked previously, but today it suddenly doesn't work and returns error messages.

```
> WR_access <- odbcConnectAccess2007("V:/Group/data/phenotype/W/freezes/WR/WR_2020.accdb", pwd="313dsada1")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 42000, code -1905, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid password.
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
```

I checked the password, and it is correct. I can use this password to access the Microsoft Access tables. Could anyone help me figure out the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to address this problem: remove the password from the original access file. After doing that, it works. However, I still don't have an idea why there was a problem with the password.